# How to get slender \prod symbol in display mode

Tags: symbols, amsmath, bold, boldmath

When I use \prod in math display mode it comes in darker form. How can I make it slender?

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
The following has product symbol in bold form $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\bigcup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha_i}$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `\[ ... \]` is used instead of `$$ ... $$` for math display mode, I get the same result.

P.S. Here I said bold by the look of the font. I know there is a much darker version of this symbol in the bold symbol.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean it's bigger than in inline formulas? That's wanted. It's not “bold”.

Comment: Off-topic but don't use `$$ ... $$` for display maths in LaTeX. Use `\[ ... \]` instead. (These are not equivalent.)

Comment: @egreg I want it to be bigger in displaymode, but not bold like in the image given.

Comment: @supremum It's not bold. Look at the top stroke.

Comment: @egreg well I need less darker in this case is what I mean.

Comment: @egreg It may not be bold, but have the similar effect in a typesetting. Think of a document which contains here and there such symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the standard shape of the symbol and you'll find thick side bars in most books.

However, you can use the “concrete“ version of the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

% redefine \prod prior to amsmath doing its job
\DeclareSymbolFont{slenderlargesymbols}{OMX}{ccex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\prod}{\mathop}{slenderlargesymbols}{"51}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

The following has a slender product symbol
\[
\prod_{i=1}^{n}\bigcup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha_i}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It gives an error `Command '\prod' already defined. ...l{\prod}{\mathop}{slenderlargesymbols}{"51}`

Comment: I have to use the packages too: `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}`. Without these packages your answer works fine for me.

Comment: @supremum The redefinition of `\prod` has to be done prior to loading `amsmath`. See the updated answer.

Comment: I liked. This could be the default symbol because I agree that the other is too dark.

Comment: Is there a symmetric slender symbol for the coproduct too? This would be slender product symbol rotated by 180 degrees. I guess I should change the number 51 to something else, but no idea where to look up the meaning of those numbers.

Comment: @kaba `\DeclareMathSymbol{\coprod}{\mathop}{slenderlargesymbols}{"60}`

Comment: Nice, thanks! :)